# Newrelic: Multiple agents for one Ruby app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic

I am trying to track client-side/JS errors using New Relic.

Unfortunately there is no good way of separating different errors within New Relic and I don't want client-side errors to influence overall error rate etc.

I was thinking about using a second agent to report the client-side errors to a separate New Relic app.

By looking at the New Relic gem source I haven't discovered an easy way for reporting to a specified environment or instantiating an additional agent.

Does anyone have experience solving this or familiar issues?

Thanks!

Comment: you could also take a look at errbit which is free and has js errors notifications https://github.com/errbit/errbit

Comment: @itsnikolay thanks! I already had a look but would prefer to use new relic as I am already using it for backend error tracking. I already tried airbrake and found it to be quite unreliable. I am also trying to avoid a self hosted solution.